# Horizontal scrolling with the touchpad in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, touch-event, touchpad

I am trying to add support for horizontal scrolling with the touchpad to my WPF application.

I am working on an HP laptop with a working touchpad: Under Windows -> Settings -> Touchpad it says "Your PC has a precision touchpad" and offers extensive options. The multiple finger gestures work, and two-finger swiping to scroll horizontally works on several apps that I tried; in short, the touchpad is perfectly capable of issuing multi-touch events.

Vertical scrolling and zooming already work thanks to some layer converting these touch events to mouse events, and this layer does also convert horizontal touch events to WM_MOUSEHWHEEL events, but WPF ignores those. There exists a feature request to add WM_MOUSEHWHEEL support to WPF here: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3201 but it is currently assigned to nobody, and the year is 2023.

I have found this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47457389/773113 (also here: https://blog.walterlv.com/post/handle-horizontal-scrolling-of-touchpad-en.html) but it gets dirty with `AddHook()` and `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL`, so I have the following issues with it:

- I find it hard to believe that one has to resort to such gimmicks in order to achieve something as simple and commonplace as receiving touchpad input.
- These gimmicks have a strong windows-only smell to me, whereas in the future I see one of the following happening:

  - Either Microsoft will release a cross-platform version of WPF to go with NetCore, so windows-specific gimmicks will be inapplicable, or
  - I will switch from WPF to Avalonia, in which case, windows-specific gimmicks will, again, be inapplicable.

So, I would rather not use walterlv's solution if I can avoid it.

While looking for an alternative I stumbled upon the concept of "manipulation" in WPF, and I thought that this might do it, but as it turns out, this entire manipulation mechanism of WPF for some reason applies only to touchscreens, not touchpads, even though I can see no practical difference between the two.

- I found a tutorial ([Microsoft Learn - .NET - Desktop Guide - Windows Presentation Foundation - Advanced - Walkthrough: Creating Your First Touch Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-creating-your-first-touch-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)) and implemented it (https://github.com/mikenakis/WpfTest2) but it does not detect any touchpad events at all. I tried it with DotNet 7.0 and with DotNet Framework 4.7.2, "same difference."  A [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75709633/773113) was down-voted for the folly of expecting that "manipulation" applies to touchpads.

So, is there any way to support horizontal scrolling with the touchpad in my WPF application without resorting to `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL`?

Comment: Wpf is windows only, forever. Maui is cross platform. some software houses like unity. Blazor is perhaps something else to consider.

Comment: There are plenty of issues in WPF that are resolved with Hooks. So I would suggest to use this option (at least for now). Only thing else I can think of, would be to inject into wpf WinUI2 controls, however that would be even more worse (from clean code prospective) then a simple Win32 hook